# 2D Texture Map Sorting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna

I was wondering how i could "sort" a Texture2D into different "Tiles".
I was thinking that you could create a 2D Array for maps, then make tiles according to position in the texture map and assign those to the different vales of the 2D Array. But i'm really stuck on this idea and needed some help with the code.

Comment: `Rectangle[,] map;` might be a good start. Or `Rectangle[] tiles; int[,] map;`.

Comment: How would i go about making a texture into tiles? Maybe using a for statement for the Height and Width of the texture and dividing it by the tile size i want?

Comment: Sure - give it a shot. You can pass a source rectangle to `SpriteBatch.Draw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an int[,] for the mapping of the textures, a different number in each part of the int[,] would signify a different texture, i would just use two for() loops using the GetLength() of the int[,].